# change of variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

For the problem attached, I don't understand where the 2nd double integral came from in line 4 of finding the density of $Z$. I understand up to line 3 of solving for $F_z(Z)$
Not sure why they needed the joint density function, isn't $P(X_1\le x_1)$ single variable?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

See that $P(X_1<zX_2)=P((X_1,X_2)\in B)$ where $B=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:x<zy\}$.

Comment: Can you explain why you introduced $B$?

Comment: Because you have the joint density, and i try to use it

Comment: If you parameterize $B$, you find the same region of integration

Comment: The solution suggests solving using joint density. The original problem doesn't suggest you use joint density. I don't understand why you need to use it.

Comment: Can you do the problem just with marginal densities?

Comment: Hmm no. If you have a function of both variables, you need the joint density necessarily.